# Independence of random pairs and conditional expectation

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation, independence

Let $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$ be two independent and identically distributed random pairs. Does it hold that
$$E(Y_1Y_2|X_1,X_2)=E(Y_1|X_1)E(Y_2|X_2)?$$
Why?

**Comments**

By hypothesis, the two sigma-algebras are independent $\sigma(X_1,Y_1)\perp \sigma(X_2,Y_2)$. It implies that $\sigma(Y_1)\perp \sigma(X_2,Y_2)$ and $\sigma(Y_2)\perp \sigma(X_1,Y_1)$. So $E(Y_1Y_2|X_2)=E(Y_1)E(Y_2|X_2)$ and $E(Y_1Y_2|X_1)=E(Y_2)E(Y_1|X_1)$. Is everything correct so far?
If so, my intuition says that $E(Y_1Y_2|X_2,X_1)=E(Y_1|X_1)E(Y_2|X_2)$ but I'm not quite sure how to show it.

Comment: It can be motivated by the formal computation of densities $$p(y_1, y_2 \mid x_1, x_2) = \frac{p(y_1, y_2, x_1, x_2)}{p(x_1, x_2)} = \frac{p(y_1, x_1)p(y_2, x_2)}{p(x_1)p(x_2)} = p(y_1 \mid x_1)p(y_2 \mid x_2).$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $B \in \sigma(X_1,X_2)$ be a rectangle, namely $B = \{X_1\in B_1,X_2\in B_2\}$. Then $$E(Y_1Y_2\mathbf 1_B) = E(Y_1\mathbf 1(X_1\in B_1))E(Y_2\mathbf 1(X_2\in B_2)) = E(E(Y_1\mid X_1)\mathbf 1(X_1\in B_1))E(E(Y_2\mid X_2)\mathbf 1(X_2\in B_2))$$
The term on the right is $$E[E(Y_1\mid X_1)E(Y_2\mid X_2)\mathbf 1_B ]$$
To get it for general $B\in \sigma(X_1,X_2)$, use a monotone class / $\pi-\lambda$ argument.